# How to reactively call a Meteor method referenced by a reactive variable?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-methods

I am trying to invoke a Meteor method not with a hard-coded string but with a `Session` variable which contains its name. It works once but does not re-run the method when the `Session` value is changed via `Session.set`.

Server code:

```
Meteor.methods({
  hello: function () {
    console.log("hello");
  },
  hi: function () {
    console.log("hi");
  }
});
```

Client code:

```
Session.set('say', 'hi');
Meteor.call(Session.get('say'));  // console prints hi
Session.set('say', 'hello');      // console is not printing, expected hello
```

How can I get the "new" method to be called after the `Session` value is changed, reactively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a reactive context to achieve this kind of home-made reactivity.
You can achieve this simply with [`Tracker.autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun):

```js
Session.set('say', 'hi');

Tracker.autorun(function callSayMethod() {
  Meteor.call(
    Session.get('say')
  );
});

Meteor.setTimeout(
  () => Session.set('say', 'hello'),
  2000
);
```

Spacebars [template helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers) use that kind of context to achieve reactivity in templates.

Note that you don't need [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) here. A simple [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) would be enough:

```js
const say = new ReactiveVar('hi');

Tracker.autorun(function callSayMethod() {
  Meteor.call(
    say.get()
  );
});

Meteor.setTimeout(
  () => say.set('hello'),
  2000
);
```